# compare constructors objects Java

Tags: java, compare

What an amazing platform! I hope im not asking a too stupid question but i have searched for an answer without success.

Q:
Is it possible to compare object values created by a constructor? Like if i want to make the animals fight and compare the "str" values against eachother.
My goal is to create the "fight" method in the Animal class, not in main. In that way, i can just call it like "dog.fight();

See my code for an example (sorry for my english)

```
public class Animal {

private int str;
private int agi;
private String name;
private String eyeColour;


public void set (int strenght, int agility, String _name){
    str = strenght;
    agi = agility;
    name = _name;

}
public String get (){
    System.out.println("Created a new animal named " + name +"! ");
    System.out.println(name + "'s agility is " + agi);
    System.out.println(name + "'s strenght is " + str);

    return name + str + agi;
}       

}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Animal dog = new Animal ();
    dog.set(8, 4, "Rambo");
    dog.get();

    System.out.println("");
    Animal cat = new Animal ();
    cat.set(2, 9, "Felix");
    cat.get();


}
}
```

Comment: Yes. Use `cat.str` and `dog.str` to access them.

Comment: and compare using `str.equals` not `==` since `==` compares references.

Comment: My goal is to create the "fight" method in the Animal class, not in main. In that way, i can just call it like "dog.fight();"
This is why i need to have some sort of "obj1.str % obj2.str" i imagine
EDIT: Sorry, obj1.str.equals obj2.str  // :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a method 'fight' in the Animal class the takes as parameter an Animal object and use it to return to you the result of the winner.

Here is the code :

```
public class Animal  {

    private int str;
    private int agi;
    private String name;
    private String eyeColour;


    public void set (int strenght, int agility, String _name){
        str = strenght;
        agi = agility;
        name = _name;

    }
    public String get (){
        System.out.println("Created a new animal named " + name +"! ");
        System.out.println(name + "'s agility is " + agi);
        System.out.println(name + "'s strenght is " + str);

        return name + str + agi;
    }

    public String fight(Animal rival){
        //Provide Comparison Logic Here
        if(this.str>rival.str)return this.name;
        if(this.str < rival.str)return rival.name;
        return "No One ";
    }
}


public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Animal dog = new Animal ();
        dog.set(8, 4, "Rambo");
        dog.get();

        System.out.println("");
        Animal cat = new Animal ();
        cat.set(2, 9, "Felix");
        cat.get();

        System.out.println(dog.fight(cat)+" is the winner! ");

    }
}
```

A Small side notes here:

It would be much better to use constructors instead of set Method here, as normally setter and getter are created to set or get a single variable.

Also it's better to change the name of your get Method and override toString method.

Here's the modified code:

```
public class Animal  {

    private int str;
    private int agi;
    private String name;
    private String eyeColour;


    public Animal (int str, int agi, String name){
        this.str = str;
        this.agi = agi;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String description = "Created a new animal named " + name +"!\n";
        description+=name + "'s agility is " + agi+"\n";
        description+=name + "'s strenght is " + str;
        return description;
    }

    public String fight(Animal rival){
        //Provide Comparison Logic Here
        if(this.str>rival.str)return this.name;
        if(this.str < rival.str)return rival.name;
        return "No One ";
    }
}


public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Animal dog = new Animal (8, 4, "Rambo");
        System.out.println(dog);

        System.out.println();
        Animal cat = new Animal (2, 9, "Felix");
        System.out.println(cat);

        System.out.println(dog.fight(cat)+" is the winner! ");

    }
}
```

Comment: Better not have two animals with the same name :) Or an animal that is called "Draw" :)))

Comment: @Matt :D :D Thanks for pointing out that :) I've Edited that :)

Comment: @Ahmed, why not return the Animal instance instead of the name? And 'null' if there is no winner. Assume that you have two dogs called Rambo that fight each other, your return value would be ambiguous.

Comment: @Matt Ofcourse! You could do that also! I'm Just clarifying the usage of comparing 2 objects in a method in the class.

Comment: Then I'd say, 'goal reached' :)